# Не работает вывод в файл в Visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, файлы, visual-c++, вывод

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct book {
    char title[15];
    char author[15];
    int value;
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int n;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("my.txt", "w");
    cout << "Vvedite kol-vo knig: ";
    cin >> n;
    book* libry = new book[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Vvedite nazvanie knigi: ";
        cin >> libry[i].title;
        cout << "Vvedite nazvaniya authora: ";
        cin >> libry[i].author;
        cout << "Vvedite zeny knigi: ";
        cin >> libry[i].value;
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "nazvaniya: " << libry[i].title << endl;
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n",libry[i].title);

        cout << "author: " << libry[i].author << endl;
        fprintf(fp,"%d\n", libry[i].author);

        cout << "zena: " << libry[i].value << endl;
        fprintf(fp,"%d\n", libry[i].value);
        cout << endl;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Я пробовал запускать в visual 2019 но он не выводит в файл, я попробовал запустить в visual 2010 и dev cpp но там выводились цифры которые не как не относятся к программе. Из за чего это может быть? Только начал изучить структуры до этого делал массивы и их выводило.

Comment: "не работает" это не описание проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы понимаете, для чего `%d` в строке

```
fprintf(fp,"%d\n", libry[i].author);
```

? Для вывода **целых чисел**. Для вывода строк используется `%s`, отдельных символов - `%c` и [так далее](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Но зачем вы вообще используете в C++ функции из C?

Пишете

```
ofstream fp("my.txt");
```

и просто дублируете вывод в `cout`:

```
cout << "author: " << libry[i].author << endl;
fp << "author: " << libry[i].author << endl;
```

Comment: а вообще чисто мнение. `freopen` это С чистый или в С++ тоже нормально использовать?

Comment: @pavel Я не догматик :), так что если бы человек использовал `prinf` - я бы ничего не говорил о `fprintf`. Но использовать столь разнородные варианты вывода? зачем? А так - как по мне, можно использовать все, что помогает решить задачу и не запутывает программиста :)

Comment: "Но зачем вы вообще используете в C++ функции из C?"
я не знаю что используется в С и что в С++, спасибо за ответ

Comment: теперь он ругается на `ofstream fp;`

Comment: Ну так добавьте `#include <fstream>`. Неужели это тоже надо рассказывать?...